# Chrome: when opening Youtube links, the video pauses after 1 sec, have to click play to continue

Tags: macos, catalina, google-chrome, youtube, web-browser

When I click a Youtube link in Chrome, it opens a tab with that particular Youtube link and starts playing.

However, for some strange reason, after playing for about 1 second it pauses the video. I have to click 'play' to continue.

For example, I visit youtube.com and click any of the suggested videos. It will open the page for that video and start playing automatically - for one second. Then it pauses.

Things I have already tried:

- updated Chrome (already using latest version)
- used Youtube with or without being logged in to Google
- removed all add-ons and extensions
- emptied cache, history, cookies, local storage, everything
- closed and restarted Chrome, with all add-ons and extensions and cookies and history removed
- rebooted my entire machine

All to no avail. I also tested in other browsers and it doesn't happen in Brave or Firefox or Safari or Vivaldi, only in Chrome.

What could possible cause this?

P.S. FYI I'm using macOS 10.15.4 Catalina (with all latest updates)

Comment: It may have something to do with an video autoplay blocker?

Comment: @PL Thanks but I have no idea what that is. Do you mean an add-on or extension? Note I removed all those, problem still occurs. Or is that a feature within chrome itself? In that case do you know how or where I can disable it?

Comment: It is an extension which I currently use to mimic Safari’s autoplay blocker. I am also aware that YouTube also has a built in auto play feature and it may have an effect on your unexpected pauses when playing a video.